# Oracle read File from Directory with exception

Tags: sql, oracle, function, exception

I'm reading files from a Directory with the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION loadBlobFromFile(p_file_name VARCHAR2) RETURN BLOB AS
  dest_loc  BLOB := empty_blob();
  src_loc   BFILE := BFILENAME('TMT', p_file_name);
BEGIN
  -- Open source binary file from OS
  DBMS_LOB.OPEN(src_loc, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);

  -- Create temporary LOB object
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(
        lob_loc => dest_loc
      , cache   => true
      , dur     => dbms_lob.session
  );

  -- Open temporary lob
  DBMS_LOB.OPEN(dest_loc, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READWRITE);


    -- Load binary file into temporary LOB
    DBMS_LOB.LOADFROMFILE(
        dest_lob => dest_loc
      , src_lob  => src_loc
      , amount   => DBMS_LOB.getLength(src_loc));

  exception 
    when DBMS_LOB.operation_failed
    then
     return empty_blob();


 -- Close lob objects
  DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(dest_loc);
  DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(src_loc);

   -- Return temporary LOB object
  RETURN dest_loc;

END loadBlobFromFile;
/
```

I call the function with

```
select loadBlobFromFile('TESTl.doc') from dual;
```

When the File exists in the directory, I get the file. When the file doesn't exist, I get the empty Blob.

Now there is one last problem. When the File has a size of 0 Byte I get an error.

Can somebody help me to improve the function with an exception and return an empty_blob() when the dbms_lob.open fails?

Thank Your Very Much!

Comment: use can user defined exception to return empty_clob()

Answer (score 0):

add an exception like this.

```
  -- Open temporary lob
  DBMS_LOB.OPEN(dest_loc, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READWRITE);

  begin
    -- Load binary file into temporary LOB
    DBMS_LOB.LOADFROMFILE(
        dest_lob => dest_loc
      , src_lob  => src_loc
      , amount   => DBMS_LOB.getLength(src_loc));

  exception 
    when dbms_lob.operation_failed
    then
      return empty_blob();
  end;
..rest of your code.
```

Comment: Thanky You! Now, files that don't exist, don't make problems any more

Answer (score 0):

I found the resolution. 
Here is my final code with help from 
http://www.toadworld.com/KNOWLEDGE/KnowledgeXpertforOracle/tabid/648/TopicID/DLP1/Default.aspx

The code of the function:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION loadBlobFromFile(p_file_name VARCHAR2) RETURN BLOB AS
  dest_loc  BLOB := empty_blob();
  src_loc   BFILE := BFILENAME('Directoryname', p_file_name);
BEGIN
  BEGIN

    -- Open source binary file from OS
    DBMS_LOB.OPEN(src_loc, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);

    -- Create temporary LOB object
    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(
          lob_loc => dest_loc
        , cache   => true
        , dur     => dbms_lob.session
    );

    -- Open temporary lob
    DBMS_LOB.OPEN(dest_loc, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READWRITE);


    -- Load binary file into temporary LOB
    DBMS_LOB.LOADFROMFILE(
        dest_lob => dest_loc
      , src_lob  => src_loc
      , amount   => DBMS_LOB.getLength(src_loc));


   exception 
    when DBMS_LOB.operation_failed --Wenn die Datei nicht vorhanden ist
    then
      DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(src_loc);
       return empty_blob();
    when DBMS_LOB.INVALID_ARGVAL  --Wenn die Datei 0 KB gross ist.
    then
      DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(dest_loc);
  DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(src_loc);
       return empty_blob();
  END;

 -- Close lob objects
  DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(dest_loc);
  DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(src_loc);

     -- Return temporary LOB object
  RETURN dest_loc;

END loadBlobFromFile;
/
```

Call the function:

```
select loadBlobFromFile('test.doc') from dual;
```

greetz