# Oracle9i send HTML email with specific characters

Tags: oracle, email, plsql, oracle9i

**Context :** I am trying to send mails with an Oracle Procedure (only html/text, not text/plain). **I use Oracle 9i**.

**Problem :** When the html message contains some characters like **& eacute;** (é), it ignores it, it only writes **;**.
But when i write directly **é** in the html message, it sends **e** wich is better.

Examples :

**message send :**

```
l_html := '<html>
            <head><title>Test HTML message</title></head>
                  <p>trying à with accent : à</p>
                  <p>trying HTML encoding of foreign language characters : &agrave;
            </body>
            </html>';
```

**message receive :**

```
trying a with accent : a

trying HTML encoding of foreign language characters : ;
```

Is it possible to transform both to the same later "a" or "à" using Oracle 9i ?

**Some code that i use :**

```
l_boundary      CONSTANT VARCHAR2(255) DEFAULT 'a1b2c3d4e3f2g1';

l_temp := l_temp || 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || carriageReturn;     
l_temp := l_temp || 'To: ' || p_to || carriageReturn;          
l_temp := l_temp || 'Cc: ' || p_cc || carriageReturn;           
l_temp := l_temp || 'From: ' || p_from || carriageReturn;
l_temp := l_temp || 'Subject: ' || p_subject || carriageReturn;
l_temp := l_temp || 'Reply-To: ' || p_from || carriageReturn;
l_temp := l_temp || 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=' || CHR(34) || l_boundary || CHR(34) || carriageReturn; 

-- Write the HTML boundary
l_temp := carriageReturn || carriageReturn || '--' || l_boundary || carriageReturn;
l_temp := l_temp || 'content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1252' || carriageReturn || carriageReturn;
l_offset := dbms_lob.getlength(l_body_html) + 1;
dbms_lob.WRITE(l_body_html, LENGTH(l_temp), l_offset, l_temp);
```

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

You declared `charset=windows-1252` - is this really the character set of your database?

Check with this query:

```
SELECT PARAMETER, VALUE
FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS
WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';
```

Strings are written in character set of your database, you should not hard-code `charset=windows-1252`, better use

```
SELECT 'charset='||UTL_I18N.MAP_CHARSET(VALUE) 
FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS
WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';
```

Consider to use `NCLOB` instead of `CLOB`. In this case above query must be `WHERE parameter = 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET'` instead.

... and even more: consider to migrate your **15 years old** database release!

**Update**

try

```
buffer VARCHAR2(4000);

ClobLen := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(l_html);
LOOP
    EXIT WHEN l_offset > ClobLen;
    DBMS_LOB.READ(l_html, 1000, l_offset, buffer);
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_RAW_DATA(con, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(buffer));
    l_offset := l_offset + 1000;
END LOOP;
```

for the HTML body. You can also just do `UTL_SMTP.WRITE_RAW_DATA(con, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(l_html));` if your message is always smaller than 32k characters.

**Update 2**

Do you make any attachment in your mail? If not, then you do not need any `l_boundary`. Boundary is just needed to separate mail text from attachment.

Instead of `Content-Type: multipart/alternative;` try `Content-Type: text/html;` or `Content-Type: multipart/mixed;` in case you like to send mails with attachment.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Effectively, the character set of our database is not windows-1252, it's WE8ISO8859P1. By the way, i can't use the query with UTL_I18N, i have an execution error **ORA-00904: "UTL_I18N"."MAP_CHARSET": identicateur non valide**. Thie migration is pending, but i need to find a solution before that the migration complete ^^

Comment: And by the way, when i use **charset=WE8ISO8859P1**, my example email send **$eacute;** instead of **;**. It does not resolve my problem :/

Comment: It should be `charset=ISO-8859-1`. `WE8ISO8859P1` is the Oracle character set name, you must use the IANA name.

Comment: Duly noted ! But the result is still the same.

Comment: Stupid question: Do you get correct output when you run `select 'trying à with accent : à' from dual;`?

Comment: My emails might be more than 32k characters, so i send them in 1900 byte chunks to UTL_SMTP. I tried to replace my utl_smtp.write_data with UTL_SMTP.WRITE_RAW_DATA like your update, but the result is still the same.

Comment: @nbadaud, please have a look at my last update. If it does not help I have not further idea. Check also this post [How to send email using Oracle 10g](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691487/how-to-send-email-using-oracle-10-g-forms/34697156?noredirect=1#comment57140976_34697156) to get a full procedure

Comment: Thank you, i'll try this as soon as possible.
I'll check the full procedure in 10g too.

Comment: I tried to modify the content-type to text/html and multipart/mixed but the $eacute is still in the mail. I understand about boundary, that it is not usefull right now because i don't have attachments, but i will keep it for later.