# sending mail attachment using UTL_SMTP plsql package

Tags: oracle, email, plsql, oracle11g

I am learning how to send one email and attachment using oracle plsql package : utl_smtp.

Can someone please share one working code which will send one simple file named : attachment1.txt having a sample content : "hello world".

Comment: Have a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691487/how-to-send-email-using-oracle-10-g-forms/34697156?noredirect=1#comment57140976_34697156

Comment: thank you.. the sample code from that link worked..

Comment: could you please also let know what changes should we make in the code for attaching one csv file from the UTL_file directory.

Comment: Open a new question. How to load a text  file into CLOB