# How do I attach file from directory to email sent with utl_smtp

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can someone please share the list of steps to be followed or a sample code to attach a simple `csv` or `Xls` file from `utl file directory` and send it through email using `utl smtp` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one to read a text file from file system:

```
FUNCTION GetFile(FolderName IN VARCHAR2, FileName IN VARCHAR2) RETURN CLOB IS

    v_bfile   BFILE; 
    v_clob    CLOB; 
    destOffset INTEGER := 1; 
    srcOffset INTEGER := 1; 
    lang_context INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.default_lang_ctx;
    warning INTEGER;

BEGIN 
    v_bfile := BFILENAME (FolderName, FileName); 
    DBMS_LOB.OPEN (v_bfile); 
    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(v_clob, TRUE, DBMS_LOB.SESSION);   
    DBMS_LOB.LOADCLOBFROMFILE(
        dest_lob => v_clob, 
        src_bfile => v_bfile, 
        amount => DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(v_bfile), 
        dest_offset => destOffset, 
        src_offset => srcOffset,
        bfile_csid => DBMS_LOB.default_csid,
        lang_context => lang_context,
        warning => warning); 

    DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(v_bfile); 

    RETURN v_clob; 

END GetFile;
```

After you read the file into CLOB you can pass it to this procedure: [How to send email using Oracle 10 g Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691487/how-to-send-email-using-oracle-10-g-forms/34697156?noredirect=1#comment57140976_34697156)

Comment: Will this attach file or will this take the text from the file and then you can use the text in email? Or using the text create a new file? How is attaching the file to email happening?

Comment: To previously asked this question: [sending mail attachment using UTL_SMTP plsql package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41085446/sending-mail-attachment-using-utl-smtp-plsql-package). This function just reads a file and copies content into CLOB variable. This variable you can use in further procedures, for example to attach it to a mail.