# Send SQL query output as CSV attachment (pl/sql)

Tags: oracle

I have a pl/sql query and I want it's output to be sent in email in CSV format straightaway. I have no directory to first create and save a CSV file and then pick it up to send as an attachment.

Please help with your inputs as I am not able to get away.

Regards,
Sachin

Comment: [Edit] your question and show us the source code of your stored procedure. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). [edit] your question do not post code or additional information in comments

Comment: You said you have PL/SQL code - so you need to show us that stored procedure

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name   I am not sure what difference that will make. That code returns the data that I need to save into an attachment. It can be anything like (SELECT 1,2 FROM DUAL) etc.

Comment: `SELECT 1,2 FROM DUAL` is not a PL/SQL procedure, it's a SQL query. SQL does the queries, PL/SQL is the programming language. There is no such thing as a "plsql query".

Comment: If it's a pointer that you want then look at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41089353/how-do-i-attach-file-from-directory-to-email-sent-with-utl-smtp  followed by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691487/how-to-send-email-using-oracle-10-g-forms/34697156?noredirect=1#comment57140976_34697156.

Comment: Often people ask for PL/SQL when they mean SQL. When you say "plsql query" it's confusing.

Comment: @BriteSponge everywhere I am getting an example where i  see the file is being picked from a directory. By now, I know how to do that. My problem is to send a mail that has an attachment created dynamically that contains the query result. As I have said earlier, I don't have any directory where I will first store a CSV file and then pick it to send it as an attachment.

Answer (score 4):

Finally figured out a solution with the help of pointers received and providing the same to further help in case someone else needs in future.

My problem was that I was mostly seeing the examples where i could either save the file on a directory or pick the file from a directory to send as an attchment but I had no provision of directory and I wanted query result to be put in CSV and sent in email dynamically. So here is the complete solution.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  SEND_CSV_ATTACHMENT AS
    v_sender                        VARCHAR2(130);
    v_recipients                    VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_cc                            VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_bcc                           VARCHAR2(2000);
    v_subj                          VARCHAR2(200);
    v_msg                           CLOB;
    v_mime                          VARCHAR2(40);
    v_tbl                             VARCHAR2(20000);
    c_cr_lf                       CONSTANT CHAR (2) := (CHR (13) || CHR (10)); -- Carriage Return/Line Feed characters for formatting text emails
    v_loop_count            PLS_INTEGER := 0;
    v_attachment            CLOB;


      v_block_qry VARCHAR2(3000); 
      v_block_row VARCHAR2(6000); 
    TYPE bl_cur IS REF CURSOR;
    v_result bl_cur;
    v_rowcount NUMBER;
    errMsg      VARCHAR2(15000);   
    
  BEGIN
    
      v_sender := 'somesender@xyzcommunications.com';      
      
      SELECT NVL(EMAIL_LIST, 'someone@abcd.com')   
      FROM
      (
        SELECT LISTAGG(EMAIL_ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY EMAIL_ID) AS EMAIL_LIST FROM RECIPEINTS_TABLE WHERE SEND_TO = 1 AND IS_ACTIVE = 1
      );     
      
      SELECT NVL(EMAIL_LIST, 'someone@abcd.com')   
      FROM
      (
        SELECT LISTAGG(EMAIL_ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY EMAIL_ID) AS EMAIL_LIST FROM RECIPEINTS_TABLE WHERE SEND_CC = 1 AND IS_ACTIVE = 1
      );    
      
          
      v_bcc := 'someone@abcd.com';

      -- Generate attachment - Begin 
      v_attachment := '"COL1", "COL2"' || CHR(13) || CHR(10);
      

      v_block_qry := 'SELECT ''"'' || COL1 || ''", "'' || COL2 ||  ''"'' AS ROWTXT        
                      FROM MY_TABLE';


      OPEN v_result FOR v_block_qry;
        LOOP 
        v_rowcount := v_result%ROWCOUNT;
        FETCH v_result INTO v_block_row;
          EXIT WHEN v_result%NOTFOUND;          
          v_attachment := v_attachment || v_block_row || chr(13) || chr(10);
        END LOOP;
      CLOSE v_result;

      -- Generate attachment - End

     

    v_subj:= 'MAIL_SUBJECT ' || TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE-1), 'YYYY-MM-DD');

      UTL_MAIL.send_attach_varchar2(sender => v_sender,
      recipients        => v_recipients,
      cc                => v_cc,
      bcc               => v_bcc,
      subject           => v_subj,
      message           =>  v_msg,
      mime_type         => 'text/html; charset=us-ascii', -- send html e-mail
      attachment        => v_attachment, 
      att_inline        => FALSE,
      att_filename      => 'Change_Report' || TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE-1), 'YYYY-MM-DD') || '.csv');
  EXCEPTION    
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    errMsg := SQLERRM;    
    SEND_MAIL_HTML ('someone@abcd.com', NULL, NULL, errMsg, 'SEND_MAIL ERROR: ' || errMsg);   

END SEND_CSV_ATTACHMENT;
```

Comment: I am using a table to store recipients and setting them as, to,cc or bcc as required.

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution. I needed to do exactly the same thing: sending a csv by mail without having to store the file. That did the trick ! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You may create such a procedure :

```
create or replace procedure prFileSend is
  v_mail_owner varchar2(100):='myname@someComp.com';
  v_url        varchar2(4000);
  v_rep        varchar2(4000);
  delimiter    varchar2(1) := chr(38);
begin
   for c in ( select * from myTable ) 
   loop
   begin
         v_url := 'http://www.mycompany.com/einfo/default.aspx?email='||c.email || delimiter || 'p1=' || c.col1 || delimiter ||'p2='||c.col2;
         v_rep := utl_http.request(utl_url.escape(v_url, false,'ISO-8859-9'));
    end;
    end loop;
exception
  when others then
    prErrorMsgSend(v_mail_owner,'Error : ' || sqlerrm); -- a function like this one which sends an error message back to you.   
end;
```

and create a scheduler job

```
begin
dbms_scheduler.create_job (
   job_name           =>  'jbFileSend ',
   job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
   job_action         =>  'prFileSend',
   start_date         =>  '22-jan-2018 09:00:00 am',
   repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY; INTERVAL=1',
   comments           =>  'Sending Every day'
   enabled            =>   true);
end;
```

working every day as an example.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but could you please clarify why this url in the loop?

Comment: @SachinVaidya To be able to send to every individual mail owner recorded in the table. You're welcome.