# Adding html feature to utl_smtp is not shown in gmail but shown when save as a .html file and open in browser

Tags: html, database, oracle, plsql, gmail

So below is my code. I am able to sent to my email address but the mail just display my whole html code. However, when i save it as a html file and open it in a browser, it is able to display normally. What seems to be the problem? Do gmail support html?

```
UTL_SMTP.write_data(mail_conn, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.write_data(mail_conn, 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="' || l_boundary || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  IF p_message IS NOT NULL THEN
UTL_SMTP.write_data(mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.write_data(mail_conn, 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.write_data(mail_conn, p_message);
UTL_SMTP.write_data(mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  END IF;
  IF p_html_message IS NOT NULL THEN
UTL_SMTP.write_data(mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.write_data(mail_conn, 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.write_data(mail_conn, p_html_message);
UTL_SMTP.write_data(mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  END IF;
UTL_SMTP.write_data(mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || '--' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
utl_smtp.close_data(mail_conn);
utl_smtp.quit(mail_conn);
p_returnCode :=0;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  p_returnCode :=SQLCODE;
  p_err_msg :=SQLERRM;
END;
```

This is how i call my package.

```
 DECLARE
 l_html VARCHAR2(32767);
 BEGIN
 l_html := '<html>
 <head>
 <title>Test HTML message</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p>This is a <b>HTML</b> <i>version</i> of the test message.</p>
 <p><img src="http://oracle-base.com/images/site_logo.gif" alt="Site Logo"     />
</body>
[![enter image description here][1]][1]</html>';
SENDMAIL('my@gmail.com', 'This is a test message', l_html);
END;
```

The below picture is the one that i save the code as html file and display it in a browser.
[image]
[image]
The above picture is what being display in my gmail inbox.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34697156/3027266

Answer (score 3):

Your code is telling the server that the message you are sending is text so its going to display it as text.

> 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"'

try telling it that its html instead.

> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: I already change to 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' but it still does not display in html format but text format.