# Pass the attachment correctly to UTL_MAIL.SEND_ATTACH_RAW

Tags: oracle, plsql

Say i have two files with the same filename `sample.xlsx` 
in two separate directories `u1\data\out1\` and `u2\data\out2\`
both of these directories already have entried in `DBA_DIRECTORIES` as `EXT_OUT1` and `EXT_OUT2`, respectively.

I would like to send `sample.xlsx` from `EXT_OUT1` using `UTL_MAIL.SEND_ATTACH_RAW`,
how can i pass it correctly to the `attachment` parameter?

Sample Anonymous Block (Note the comments):

```
DECLARE

    vInHandle       utl_file.file_type;
    l_sender        varchar2(100)   := 'SO@SO.com';
    l_recipients    varchar2(100)   := 'migs.isip.23@gmail.com';
    l_subject       varchar2(100)   := 'Employee Roster Report';
    l_message       varchar2(100)   := 'Hello';
    l_attachment    raw;
    l_directory     varchar2(100)   := 'EXT_OUT1';
    fname           varchar2(100)   := 'sample.xlsx';


BEGIN

    /* how put RAW data into l_attachment here? */
    --vInHandle := utl_file.fopen(l_directory, fname, 'R'); -- If i'm not mistaken, this reads the File from the specified directory
    --utl_file.get_raw();                                   -- not sure what parameters i should pass
    --utl_file.fclose(vInHandle);                           -- ?

    UTL_MAIL.SEND_ATTACH_RAW
    (
        sender       => l_sender
    ,  recipients   => l_recipients
    ,  subject      => l_subject
    ,  message      => l_message
    ,  attachment   => l_attachment
    ,  att_filename => 'clouds.jpg'
    ); 

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        raise_application_error(-20001,'The following error has occured: ' || sqlerrm); 
END;
```

Comment: What happens when you run that? The 5th argument should be a RAW value, not a string; and the 6th is the name of the attachment *in the email*. It doesn't look at any directory. [See a demo here](http://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/pkgs/utl_mail.html).

Comment: hi @AlexPoole, yes apologies on that, i edited the question, kindly let me know how i should pass `l_attachment` to the `attachment` parameter.

Comment: You can attach only a single document with this procedure. Also note, the size of RAW is limited to 32k. Is this sufficient for your needs?

Comment: Hi @WernfriedDomscheit, yes i'll only attach a single `xlsx` file. maybe at around 4 MB. by 32k do you mean 32 kilobytes?

Comment: Yes it means 32k byte

Comment: i see. in this case, i don't think `UTL_MAIL` will be sufficient for my requirement. any alternatives you might suggest? @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: In this case you have to use the low-level package [UTL_SMTP](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_smtp.htm). Use this post to get a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691487/how-to-send-email-using-oracle-10-g-forms/34697156#34697156 In order to attach BLOB [google for "utl_smtp blob attachment"](https://www.google.ch/search?q=utl_smtp+blob+attachment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attachment content is the value you are supplying as the attachment parameter. The filename is simply a label. It doesn't read the file, so you'd have to do that yourself and then assign that as the attachment.

Comment: Hi @gary-myers, that's the part i'm not sure about. How can i pass the actual `RAW` file to the `attachment` parameter? i'm seeing posts that `utl_file.fopen` would do the trick but i'm not quite sure how to proceed. Thank you!