# How to send a mail to a set of people everytime a particular table's data is modified in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, database-trigger, email

I have a table with configuration settings which has a column containing 'Key Values".

I have an audit table which captures all the insert/updates/deletes on this configuration table on the "key value" column, using a trigger.

My requirement is that, anytime this audit table gets a new record (which means my parent configuration key value has been changed), a mail should be sent to a group of people about the change.

How can I go about doing that?

Thank You!

Comment: The simple part is the code: use the Oracle library package [`utl_mail`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/UTL_MAIL.html#GUID-47AE34E9-3123-4115-AC86-4FF538DBFBBB). The more complicated bit is access to an email server. Does your database server have an email server installed? Is the database configured to use it? If you don't know the answers to those questions you'll need to talk to your DBA and/or your sysadmin/network admin, and maybe your security team too.

Comment: Yes, we have the required email server installed. Could you please provide an example using utl_smtp for achieving the same?

Comment: Please read [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34691487/146325)